# DIN A5 PDF on Kindle Paperwhite 2

Tags: pdf, kindle-paperwhite

What PDF paper sizes does Kindle Paperwhite 2 supports? I'm generating a ebook from sources, so I can specify a size. But when I use any paper size (like A5, or B7) different from default (portrait letter) I cannot read it. The PDF even doen't show up on my home. Portrait letter book is ok.

Also, "Send to Kindle" fails with no sane reason when trying to upload this book.

Comment: Ereaders work best with formats that support reflowable text, like epub or azw for Kindles, instead of fixed page formats like pdf.

Comment: @Sekhemty, sure, I know that. Just curious why I can't see my book which is on a device.